# Fetching weather data from Foreca weather API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch weather data from Foreca Weather api (https://rapidapi.com/foreca-ltd-foreca-ltd-default/api/foreca-weather/).
To fetch current weather, location parameter is required which is a string of numbers different for different cities. This location parameter can be fetched from their location search endpoint.

I have a function searchCity which fetches location id  and then passes it to the weatherUrl to fetch the current weather.
The first time I search for a city I do get the locations array, but not the current weather and axios throws 400 bad request error.
The second time I search it gives me both, but the current weather response is from the last api call.

Here's the code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const Home = () => {
  // const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([""]);
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});


  const url = `https://foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com/location/search/${city}`
  let weatherUrl;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'apiKeyHere',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };
  const weatherOptions = {
    params: { alt: '0', tempunit: 'C', windunit: 'MS', tz: 'Europe/London', lang: 'en' },
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'apiKeyHere',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

  const searchCity = async (e) => {
    try {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        await axios.get(url, options).then((response) => {
          setLocation(response.data.locations);
          console.log(response.data);
          weatherUrl = `https://foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com/current/${location[0]?.id}`;
        })
        setCity('')
        // To show the current weather of the city searched
        currentWeather(); 


      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  const currentWeather = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get(weatherUrl, weatherOptions).then((response) => {
        setWeather(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

  }
  return (
    <> <div>
        <div className="search">
          <input
            value={city}
            onChange={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
            onKeyPress={searchCity}
            type="text" />
        </div>

        <div className="weather">
          <h1>City:{location[0]?.name}</h1>
          <h1>Country:{location[0]?.country}</h1>
          <h1>id:{location[0]?.id}</h1>
          <h1>weather:{weather.current?.temperature}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>

  )
}

export default Home;
```

What am I doing wrong or are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a possible race condition / async problem. Here is how you do it with plain Javascript https://www.visualcrossing.com/resources/documentation/weather-api/how-to-load-weather-data-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Removed axios and just used fetch instead and now it works fine.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([]);
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const url = `https://foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com/location/search/${city}`
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'apiKeyHere',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };
  const weatherOptions = {
    params: { alt: '0', tempunit: 'C', windunit: 'MS', tz: 'Europe/London', lang: 'en' },
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'apiKeyHere',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };


  let weatherUrl;

  const searchCity = async (e) => {
    try {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        fetch(url, options)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            setLocation(response.locations)
            weatherUrl = `https://foreca-weather.p.rapidapi.com/current/${response.locations[0]?.id}`;
            currentWeather();
          })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  const currentWeather = async () => {
    try {
      fetch(weatherUrl, weatherOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          setWeather(response.current);
          console.log(response.current);
        })
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <> <div>
      <div className="search">
        <input
          value={city}
          onChange={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
          onKeyPress={searchCity}
          type="text" />
      </div>

      <div className="weather">
        <h1>City:{location[0]?.name}</h1>
        <h1>Country:{location[0]?.country}</h1>
        <h1>id:{location[0]?.id}</h1>
        <h1>weather:{weather.temperature}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```